# Why Use Skin if we can STILL handle Server Controls with CSS in Asp.Net?

Tags: css, webforms, theming, skins

The main difference between Theme/Skins and CSS are the HTML & Server Side Controls (SSC) only. We use Skin files to format & cosmetics SSC which are not in HTML like `<asp:Label>`, `<asp:TextBox>` & `</asp:RadioButtonList>` etc...

BUT what if we use the rendered HTML SSC in CSS instead Skin files to handle `<asp:Label>` & `<asp:TextBox>` etc... ie: when SSC `<asp:TextBox>` rendered on browsers it shows `<input type="text">` so if we write following style in my CSS file instead Skin, it also works...

```
 input[type=text], textarea, select 
  { 
    outline: none; 
    padding: 3px 0px 3px 3px; 
    margin: 5px 1px 3px 0px; 
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    background: #ffffff;  
    width: 150px; 
    color: #484848; 
    font-size: 12px; 
  }
```

So my question is, if we STILL can handle SSC with CSS do we REALLY need SKINS? Or if I am missing anything please correct me, thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.skin vs .css from asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034313/skin-vs-css-from-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

webforms concentrates on server side processing. When webforms was first introduced it favored styling controls via control properties rather than CSS. I tend to think of skins as CCS-like styling for server side controls. You can even have the skin set the CssClass property.

CSS has improved since 2001 and, IMO, skins provide less and less value.  So do you need skins, no. Do they provide value? You would have a difficult time convincing me :)

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for your taught sharing and yes might be difficult to convince you :) but let's give it try ;-)

Comment: Since CSS improved, and Less / SaSS also been introduced do we still need Skins? Basically I am not arguing, and not at all against Skins anyway, the try to findout is there any edge or benefits of Skins of CSS for developers so-far?